# Does \renewcommand in MathJax affect other user's posts?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

In MathJax, does

```
\$\renewcommand\LaTeX{\textbf{u got hax'd}}\$
```

affect other people's posts?

This is it being used in *this* post. Definition:

> \$\renewcommand\LaTeX{\textbf{u got hax'd}}\$

Usage:

> \$\LaTeX\$

(I'm just curious, is all...)

Comment: I voted to close this... please try such things in the sandbox on mse ;) and if you want to change it: ask a [tag:feature-request] or [tag:bug] over there...

Comment: For future reference, here is a link to [the MSE Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: @RubberDuck [Can't.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment654233_87826)

Comment: @Vogel612 As I said to RubberDuck, "[Can't.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment654233_87826)" I don't care enough for a feature request or bug, either. If you really hate the question, I don't mind it closed (I have my answer) but it's not like there's anywhere better to put it.

Comment: It's not like I hate the question... it's just not a question that should be around here in this form.

Comment: @Vogel612 The close reason you've given contradicts the question: this *is* about "the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center." It's also better here than on MSE, IMHO, since it's not enabled on MSE and it's enabled *differently* on different sites (albeit I'm not sure how big those differences run).

Comment: I am OK with this question being here. It's a reasonable place for it.

Comment: Related discussion on [meta.math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4130/8348).

Comment: I had totally no idea that this was possible. Thanks for showcasing some more MathJax. We can never get enough of that stuff.

Comment: @veedrac my apologies. I didn't realize that MathJax wasn't enabled on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try it, shall we?

> \$\LaTeX\$

At the time of writing, this shows up as the modified, \$\textbf{u got hax'd}\$ variant for me, although other clients - the Android app and [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/q/4486) users - report different results.

Comment: Well there we go. Mystery solved.

Comment: If you are using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/q/4486), this answer won't appear to be hax'd. (See [Ilmari Karonen's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12502) from meta.math for more details.)

Comment: Interestingly the android app doesn't show this behavior